# Project not reading .wav files when executed from the JAR

Tags: java, audio, jar

Simple GUI application for playing sound clips after user selects one with a radio button and pushes the play button. After clean and build, execution from the JAR file results in no sound being played when a clip is selected and the play button is pushed.

Conditions: NetBeans IDE, sounds play successfully in the IDE pathed to the package, path to .wav files in JAR is correct, files are in the JAR in the correct directory, uses 2 classes: one for the GUI and a .wav handler class (both work successfully in the IDE. More details in screen shots.

[image: Project Directory]

[image: CMD output after load JAR and attempt to play sound]

[image: Directory of contents inside of the JAR using WINRAR to open]

The code snippet used to call the resource (this works fine in the IDE, so no issue there):

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()){
            URL file = QuotesButtonUI.class.getResource("/my/sounds/fear_converted.wav");
            new Player (file.getFile()).start();
    }
    else if (jRadioButton2.isSelected()){

            URL file = QuotesButtonUI.class.getResource("/my/sounds/initiated_converted.wav");
            new Player (file.getFile()).start();
    }
```

This is the Player class used to process the .wav. Within the GUI class, I am using the new Player().start() call. I am thinking that there should be a getResource() call in the Player class but I don't know for sure.

```
package my.quotesbutton;

import java.io.File; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat; 
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream; 
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem; 
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine; 
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl; 
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException; 
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine; 
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException; 

public class Player extends Thread { 

    private String filename;

    private Position curPosition;

    private final int EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE = 524288; // 128Kb 

    enum Position { 
        LEFT, RIGHT, NORMAL
    };

    public Player(String wavfile) { 
        filename = wavfile;
        curPosition = Position.NORMAL;
    } 

    public Player(String wavfile, Position p) { 
        filename = wavfile;
        curPosition = p;
    } 

    public void run() { 

        File soundFile = new File(filename);
        if (!soundFile.exists()) { 
            System.err.println("Wave file not found: " + filename);
            return;
        } 

        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = null;
        try { 
            audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e1) { 
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (IOException e1) { 
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } 

        AudioFormat format = audioInputStream.getFormat();
        SourceDataLine auline = null;
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);

        try { 
            auline = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            auline.open(format);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } 

        if (auline.isControlSupported(FloatControl.Type.PAN)) { 
            FloatControl pan = (FloatControl) auline
                    .getControl(FloatControl.Type.PAN);
            if (curPosition == Position.RIGHT) 
                pan.setValue(1.0f);
            else if (curPosition == Position.LEFT) 
                pan.setValue(-1.0f);
        } 

        auline.start();
        int nBytesRead = 0;
        byte[] abData = new byte[EXTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE];

        try { 
            while (nBytesRead != -1) { 
                nBytesRead = audioInputStream.read(abData, 0, abData.length);
                if (nBytesRead >= 0) 
                    auline.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead);
            } 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } finally { 
            auline.drain();
            auline.close();
        } 

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had an issue similar to this, try making a folder with the same path as you have inside the JAR file but outside of it. Why it works I don't know butI've had an issue similar to this, try making a folder with the same path as you have inside the JAR file but outside of it. Why it works I don't know but doing that has worked for me. Hopefully that solves your problem. doing that has worked for me. Hopefully that

Comment: My intention is to give this to folks in my office packaged as a single entity not requiring other files and dependencies. Would this work for that?

Comment: Try Jeremy's solution. Mine would require you to have an additional folder distributed with the JAR. If Jeremy's solution does work for you, would you mind commenting on here that it did so I will know and be able to adjust my program. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
try
{
    InputStream in = QuotesButtonUI.class.getResourceAsStream("/my/sounds/fear_converted.wav");
    if (in != null)
    {
        //code to play sound here
    }
}
catch (IOException ioe)
{

}
```

Comment: So instead of .getFile(), what method would you use to fetch the stream?

Comment: Not sure this is a good fit since I need to use the resource as a file. My Player class works fine in this project with an absolute path or from within the IDE. The only problem is once I build it out to a jar file. Otherwise, the player renders the sound as desired/designed.

Comment: uhmm you 'link file' or 'copy file' into your netbeans java project?